# what the differences in mongoDB strategy field in replicaSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From what I have read there are 3 options :  "ping" and "strategy" and a default as null.
Can someone explain what are the differences between them ?
I am using secondary preferred so whom should I pick based the fact all my servers are in the same data center ? 
When I chose "ping" I see that most of the reading goes only to one secondary (and I have more then 1) 
So what am I missing ?

Here is my configuration :

```
dbOptions: {
        db: {
            readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred'
        },
        server: {
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            },
            readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred',
            strategy: 'ping'
        },
        replset: {
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            },
            rs_name: 'test',
            readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred',
            strategy: 'ping'
        }
    }
```

Comment: All three options ( as configured separately ) are actually deprecated and should actually be issuing a warning to that effect. The replica set name should now be used as part of the connection URI, and other options specified as "top level" configuration options rather than under `db` or `server` or `replset`, much like the deprecation warning "should" be telling you.

Comment: I would also generally advise that you do not set read preference away from the primary unless you fully understand what that means. Since you are using deprecated configuration options, I'm skeptical that you are actually fully aware of the implications. If you are looking for "load balancing" then "replication" is not the tool for that, and you should be looking at sharding instead.

Comment: ok, where can i see latest configuration so i can know exactly how to change it ?